# Parallelism with ForwardIterator?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17

I was just thinking about whether we could speed up the extraction of distinct elements that appear in a sorted `std::list<int>` by running the [parallelized version](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism) of [`std::unique_copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy).

My conception of how this would work is this:

- Split the data in sections.
- Apply the algorithm to those sections in parallel.
- Merge the results, while working out the edge cases between the sections.

But as I see this, having only a ForwardIterator instead of a RandomAccessIterator, would require at least two passes to solve this in parallel: one pass to set up the sections, next pass applies the algorithm.

I understand, that not every problem will benefit from the virtues of parallelization.

Is my conception of how this works correct (approximately)?

Then my question would be, why don't the parallel algorithms require RandomAccessIterators? Is it beneficial to support ForwardIterator here? Can the algorithms detect which type of iterator they have, and pick a more efficient version accordingly?

Comment: The last question is easy to answer. [Yes they can detect the type of iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) and can use that information when it is beneficial. Also `std::list` supports more than a forward iterator, it supports a [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) (which probably doesn't make a difference in this case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that the parallel algorithms support forward iterators is that parallelizing can improve the performance of those algorithms.

Yes, a forward iterator only moves one step at a time through the controlled sequence. But there's more to an algorithm than just movement -- you also have to look at the **other things** that the algorithm does.

For example, if copying an object is expensive, `std::copy` with forward iterators can be faster in parallel, because the time needed to copy the objects dominates the traversal time; spitting out parallel copies improves the overall speed, even though the forward iterators mean that the parallel algorithm does more work than the serial one.